# GAE javapns Push Queue

Tags: google-app-engine

so with GAE 1.7.7 there is support for outbound sockets and javapns should work...ok, I can do simple Push.payload calls, but the problem with this is it doesn't keep the connection open to APNS and because of this is very slow. Push.queue keeps open the connection but it won't work on GAE because it spawns threads and this isn't allowed there...so the question is this...how can I keep an open connection to APNS on GAE? Is there another way? Is there another open source library that can do this without spinning up threads the way that javapns is doing?

Thanks!
Jeff

Comment: There's also https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns

Comment: But all libraries will have the same problem: outgoing sockets get closed after about 2min of inactivity.

Comment: Ya, I really need the connection pooling available in javapns...guess I have to keep my notification service on aws running still. Thanks for the comments.